# Kotlin unresolved reference issue

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I was able to do everything so far except this, don't know why but I got this error `Unresolved reference:x` for last line `print(x)`.

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {

    var liste = IntRange(3,19)

    var bolundu = 1

    for (x in liste)
        for (y in IntRange(2,x))
            if (x % y != 0)
                bolundu = 0

        if (bolundu == 1)
            print(x)
}
```

I don't understand what is the problem, why it doesn't match that `x` with the one in the for loop?

Comment: Your `for x` loop only contains one statement: the `for y` loop. Use `{}` if you want multiple statements within the loop (it a good idea to use braces even for single-statement loops to make it clear where it begins and ends).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you must specify the parenthesis in Kotlin if you have more than one statement to evaluate within the loop.

Actually, your code is exactly the same of this one:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    var liste = IntRange(3,19)

    var bolundu = 1

    for (x in liste) {
        for (y in IntRange(2,x)) {
            if (x % y != 0) {
                bolundu = 0
            }
        }
    }
    if (bolundu == 1) {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

Instead, you want something like this:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    var liste = IntRange(3,19)

    var bolundu = 1

    for (x in liste) {
        for (y in IntRange(2,x)) {
            if (x % y != 0)
                bolundu = 0
        }
        if (bolundu == 1)
            print(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: @GLHF you asked how to solve the error, I can't know what's the purpose of your code